# Recursive imports with MSBuild

Tags: msbuild

In MSBuild it is possible to do a recursive import

```
<Import Project="TopLevel\**\*.targets" />
```

Does anybody know if MSBuild makes any guarantees about the order that the matching files are imported in? It is important for property evaluations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Wildcards**:
In the .NET Framework 4, MSBuild allows wildcards in the Project attribute. When there are wildcards, ***all matches found are sorted (for reproducibility), and then they are imported in that order as if the order had been explicitly set.***
This is useful if you want to offer an extensibility point so that someone else can import a file without requiring you to explicitly add the file name to the importing file. For this purpose, Microsoft.Common.Targets contains the following line at the top of the file.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92x05xfs.aspx

hope that help

Comment: It certainly does, thanks. Annoyingly, I had been on that page earlier this evening looking for something else and just missed this completely! Doh.